# Стоит ли склонять название в объявлении: "Утеряна печать (название)"?

Tags: склонение

Стоит ли склонять название в объявлении?

**Утеряна печать «Саморегулируемая организация – Ассоциация Региональное отраслевое объединение работодателей «Строители Крыма»**

Comment: Мы говорим о названии организации или о названии печати?

Comment: наверное, это её печать...

Comment: Если это текст, вырезанный на печати, то он не должен склоняться.

Comment: Или: Утеряна печать организации "Рога и копыта"

Comment: да, это просто их печать...я просклоняла Ассоциацию...и организацию

Comment: Я бы не склонял. Или *печать "Текст, вырезанный на печати"" или *печать организации "Название организации"*

Answer (score 1):

Утеряна печать следующего содержания (со следующим текстом): «Саморегулируемая организация – Ассоциация Региональное отраслевое объединение работодателей «Строители Крыма».

Answer (score 1):

Если для опознания потерянного нужно полностью передать текст печати (например, из пропавшего комплекта печатей организации дорога только эта), то процитируйте этот текст *без склонения* (**печать с текстом: "..."**). Если же хотите назвать организацию, в которой пропала ровно одна печать, то её название легко найти в тексте на печати - можно указать его без признаков классификации (вряд ли существует одноимённое не "саморегулируемое" и не "ассоциация" с похожей проблемой утраты печати), *со склонением*: **печать Регионального отраслевого объединения работодателей «Строители Крыма»**